# Unknown color name error in R when using alpha command

Tags: r, alpha

I am trying to calculate cronbach's alpha on one of my scales within my data, I have created a separate data frame

```
mv_self_scale <- data.frame(analytic_data_survey[,3:17, 33:48])
```

But when I run this line:

```
alpha(mv_self_scale)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown colour name: c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 7, 3, 5, 3, 6, NA, 4, NA, 7, 7, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 5, NA, 3, NA, 5, 6, 5, 6, NA, NA, 6, 7, NA, 6, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, 3, 7, NA, NA, 3, 1, 2, 5, NA, NA, 5, NA, 4, 6, 6, 7, 6, 4, NA, NA, 4, 7, NA, 3, 4, NA, 4, 1, NA, 7, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 2, 6, 7, 6, 6, NA, 6, 4, 5, NA, 4, NA, 7, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 5)
```

I'm not sure how to deal with it

Comment: You are accidentally using the `alpha` function from the `scales` package. Either make sure you load the `psych` package last, or be explicit by using `psych::alpha`. (I'm assuming you want to use `psych`, you didn't say.)

Comment: Repro: `library(scales); alpha(data.frame(array(0, dim = c(2, 2, 2))))`

Comment: Would like to ask; should cronbach's alpha be calculated on complete cases only or on all cases?

Comment: For me this answer helped me fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63348548/18183112